# Ensure uniqueness of a token string for the same payload but for two different use cases

Tags: jwt

I have two use cases: a. Verify Email Address b. Reset forgotten password

For JWT signing, I am just passing a user Id in the payload. Does JWT signing process make sure that two different (unique) JSON tokens be generated for these two use cases? If not, what do I need to do? Kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only when signed using a deterministic algorithm - RS and HS family, all other algorithms (ES, PS, EdDSA) are not deterministic and two tokens with the same header and payload will have different signatures.